# Why do I need to record the first element in removal in a linked list?

Tags: java, linked-list

I'm trying to implement `LinkedList` from scratch and having trouble with understanding the `deleteFirst()` method which removes the first `Link` in the list. Why do I have to save a reference of the `firstLink` to a temporary `Link` object and then return it? I do not understand why I have to assign `firstLink` reference to a `temp` object and then return it, but how come does it return the consecutive `Link` object? Why cannot I simply do this?

```
firstLink = firstLink.next;
return firstLink
```

Class `Link`:

```
public class Link {

    public String bookName;
    public int quantity;

    public Link next;

    public Link(String bookName, int quantity){
        this.bookName = bookName;
        this.quantity = quantity;
        this.next = null;
    }

    public void display(){
        System.out.println("The number of " + bookName + " is " + quantity);
    }
}

class LinkedList{

    public Link firstLink;

    public LinkedList(){
        this.firstLink = null;
    }

    public boolean isEmpty(){
        return (firstLink == null);
    }

    public void insertLink(String bookName, int quantity){
        Link newLink = new Link(bookName, quantity);
        newLink.next = firstLink;
        firstLink = newLink;
    }

    public Link deleteFirst(){
        if(this.isEmpty()){
            System.out.println("The list is empty!");
        }
        else{
            Link temp = firstLink;
            firstLink = firstLink.next;
            return temp;
        }
        return null;
    }
}
```

Comment: What would your suggestion return? What is the method supposed to return?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the beginning, your list looks like this (conceptually)

```
1    2    3
^
|
|
firstLink
```

Then, you execute `firstLink = firstLink.next`, so it now looks like this:

```
1    2    3
     ^
     |
     |
   firstLink
```

If you do `return firstLink;`, you will return `2`. However, you want to return the removed element, which is `1`.

This looks like this, after `Link temp = firstLink`:

```
1    2    3
^
|
|
firstLink AND temp
```

Then, `firstLink = firstLink.next`:

```
1       2       3
^       ^
|       |
|       |
temp    firstLink
```

Because of the temporary variable, we retain a reference to `1` even after it's been removed.

Comment: I was going to answer but this sums it up. One other thing is that you have the option of saving or working on the item after its been removed. There isn't anything wrong with your code, its just how you want to implement it.

Comment: @durron597, of course, I'll accept it. I have to wait because of the waiting minutes to accept an answer (4 mins left :) ).

Answer (score 1):

The `deleteFirst()` method has 2 responsibilities

1. To remove the 1st item on the list.
2. To return the removed item

This is because `LinkedList` implements `Deque` and those are the rules set by it. 
If you don't store it in a `temp` variable you will be unable to return it.